# Pin Find & Replace dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, is there any way I can keep the Find & Replace box pinned in the corner, as in the image below, when I move between files?

I have 10 documents open. I know I want to do search in say 3 particular files only. So All Open documents or All Files doesn't make sense.

Right now as soon as I go to second document, the box disappears. I have to do Ctrl+F for it to come back.

[image]

I know I can do some docking but I want to keep it in that corner as it is very convenient and occupies less space.

Comment: That Find dialog is an obscene PITA.

Answer (score 0):

You can click your solution/project and click Ctrl-H to open the find and replace window from there.

Comment: Sorry doesn't help on what I am looking for and I don't see any option to Find when I right click Solution or project

Comment: Yeah sorry not right click anymore. Just select your solution, click Ctrl-H and a pop-up will open.

Comment: True, I am using those shortcuts already. What I want is if I navigate to another open document, I want the box to stay open on that new document instead of me to again use Ctrl+F to open it.

Comment: When I played with the box below I found that if you changed the drop down from Current document to All open documents for example, it stayed open

![Screenshot](http://www.images.tn/upload/original/1427068454.png)

Comment: Agree. I have tried all of them and mentioned in my question. Looks like there isn't any way to pin that Find & replace as it says "Current Document" by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference, as this helped me out so posting here to help others.

Pressing CTRL + F opens up "Quick Find" which will open a small dialog box in the top corner of the file and will jump around all the files you are searching.

Pressing SHIFT + CTRL + F opens up "Find in Files" which will open up a bigger dockable dialog box which you can have floating or dock to the windows. This does take slightly longer to search, but im sure if you configure the find settings it will be quicker. The plus for me was the docking aspect.

This is on VS 2019, not sure what other versions this might be on.